# how to write sql query in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to write this code in codeigniter?
i want to convert this code in php codeigniter.

```
$query="SELECT * FROM class,student 
   WHERE class.class_name= '$name' AND student.class_id='$name'";
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please step first to [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Comment: Well I would suggest looking at the Codeigniter manual. Thats why people spend their time writing it

Comment: Refer this manual of Codeigniter 3.1 [Query Builder Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html)

Comment: in query builder class, there is some variable declared and pass the value to to this variable's. but i declare a single variable and store an array of inputs in this veriable. how i can use this variable at multi places??

Answer (score 0):

try out using active records

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('class');
$this->db->join('student', 'student.id = class.student_id'); // check the join i.e the common column
$this->db->where('class_name', $name);
$this->db->where('class_id', $name);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this query....

```
    $this->db->where('class_name',$name);
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('class');
    $this->db->join('student', 'student.class_id = class.class_name');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
```

Comment: Message: Undefined variable: name

Filename: views/vstudent.php

Line Number: 17

Comment: you have to pass variable($name) from controller to model